# Android back-button working but back via home button not working perfectly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-actionbaractivity

I have a recycler view with some data. when an item clicked, opens new `DetailsActivity`.
My trouble is when it come back from `DetailsActivity` to `MainActivity` with Back-Button (Down on the Natel) working perfectly. But when I come back via home button extends `ActionBarActivity`, load the data again from scratch. I want exactly the same return as back button in Natel below.
does anyone have an Idea?

Back Code in onOptionsItemSelected Methord:

```
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);

// NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); // also tried
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, instead of starting the activity over, just call `finish()` on your current activity.

Basically when you click an item you are calling the below correct (or something along those lines)?

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
```

If so, then once you are in your `Detailsactivity`, just call:

```
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
    finish();
}
```

That will finish the `Detailsactivity` which was shown over your `MainActivity` and return you to the exact same spot you were at.

Comment: Hi Zamereon, much thanks for your answer. but it is still not working. 
I want also return to the exact same spot i where i was. its working with back button on device. with code it not working.. :(

Comment: The back button as in the physical back button on the device correct? If so, then calling `onBackPressed()` in the `if(id == android.R.id.home)` section will call the exact method the physical button is using.

Comment: thankx Zamereon. it is working with onBackPressed();